# Read test data from excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am using POM framework and test data I kept in a properties file (This code is working without any issue) but as per the current requirement, I should keep the test data in excel file. As per my code data is reading from excel but values are not sending to chrome(i cross-checked by printing the values in the console) when I debug I got to know that Data is returning a null value. The issue is with p.load(fs1); Line because data is not loading.

```
// below code is for properties file and its working without any issue.
/*    public static String readTestData(String key) throws IOException {
            String filename = "testData";
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/testData.properties";
            if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
                path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/" + filename + ".properties";
            }
            Properties p = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(path);
             System.out.print("File Input Stream value is "+fs);
            p.load(fs);
            System.out.println("Value of login username is "+(String)p.get(key));
            return (String) p.get(key);
        }*/




// Below code is for reading test data from xlsx

public static String readTestData(String key) throws IOException {
            String filename = "testData";
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/testData.xlsx";
           if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
                path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/" + filename + ".xlsx";
            }
            Properties p = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(path);
            Workbook SapWorkbook = null;
            StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
            SapWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            Sheet SapSheet = SapWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int rowCount = SapSheet.getLastRowNum()-SapSheet.getFirstRowNum();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {

                Row row = SapSheet.getRow(i);

                //Create a loop to print cell values in a row

                for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                    //Print Excel data in console
                    sbf.append(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                    System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");

                }

                System.out.println();
            } 
            byte[] bytes = sbf.toString().getBytes();
            ByteArrayInputStream fs1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            p.load(fs1);
            System.out.println("Value of login username is "+(String)p.get(key));
           return (String) p.get(key);

        }   

 public static void enterText(String key, String data) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                waitForPresenceAndVisibilityOfElementry(readobjectRepo(key));
                WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(readobjectRepo(key)));
                ele.clear();
                Thread.sleep(1200);
                System.out.println("about to read Base page");
                ele.sendKeys(readTestData(data));
                System.out.println("data read");
                startExtent.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Entering  data.. " + readTestData(data) + " is sucessful");
                Thread.sleep(1200);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                reportFailure("Click on element is unsucessful");
            }
        }
```

---

```
In the console result.

loginUserName|| ABCD@gmail.com|| 
loginPassword|| abc@1a|| 

Value of login username is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks quite messy and could do with some clean up.  This block is pointless:

```
String filename = "testData";
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/testData.xlsx";
if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/" + filename + ".xlsx";
}
```

You are just hard coding the same thing in different ways, stick to just

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/testData.xlsx";
```

It's pretty unclear what you are trying to do here, but I'm going to guess you want the value in the second column that is associated with a key that is in the first column.  All of the stuff creating a properties object seems completely obsolete, so I've rewritten your code to be this:

```
Workbook SapWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
Sheet SapSheet = SapWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
int rowCount = SapSheet.getLastRowNum() - SapSheet.getFirstRowNum();
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
    Row row = SapSheet.getRow(i);
    if (key.equals(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue())) {
        return row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    }
}

throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s not found!", key));
```

This will now scroll through each row searching for the first instance of your "key" and will then return the associated "value".  If it doesn't find a key it will throw an exception.  To package it all up as a single method:

```
public static String readTestData(String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/testData.xlsx";
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(path);
    Workbook SapWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet SapSheet = SapWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int rowCount = SapSheet.getLastRowNum() - SapSheet.getFirstRowNum();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
        Row row = SapSheet.getRow(i);
        if (key.equals(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue())) {
            return row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s not found!", key));
}
```

Comment: HI Ardesco,
i have list test data in excel but it reads row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()) & row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue() {reading only email id and password},i dont wnat to hard code can u please suggest

Comment: Depends upon the structure of your excel document.  getCell(0) is getting the data from the first column (I'm guessing this is the column that has identifiers for your data) and getCell(1) is getting the data from the second column (I'm guessing this has your data).  In the above comment I would expect you to be getting an identifier and some associated data, not sure why you want to join those together?

Comment: i dont want to join together, my test data has 50 rows and 4 column, column 1 will be stable and column 2,3,4 data will be change, how i can read can u help

Comment: loginUserName abc@123.com
loginPassword        XXXXXX
customer_name abc0012
customer_Code 123456
SFDC aoa_1205
customer_PhoneNo 12345
customer_Code 1827465
contact_Persion_Other Other
So on.....................

Comment: post completion of read test data from 2nd column it should go for 3rd column (It has different data for 2nd cycle)

Comment: If you want to get the data from the third column instead of the second column use `row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue()` instead

Comment: You could return the row of data, rather than a specific data item with your readTestData method.  This is feeling like a different question to the one originally asked now though.

Comment: i tried all the method i dont want to hard code it like mentioning row values, you gave me this code ryt,  for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
        Row row = SapSheet.getRow(i);
        if (key.equals(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue())) {
            return row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        }
    },same way can u help me to read complete excel file n excecute, same as what i wrote for excel file ?

Comment: If the above answer has answered your original question correctly, you should mark it as a correct answer.  If the comments above and the answer haven't given you enough information to solve a different problem, you should another question with all the relevant details (including structure of the Excel file).  Comments aren't really the place to try and help you with a related but different problem

Comment: HI Ardesco, can u please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629895/unable-to-read-test-data-from-excel-file and help in resolving

Comment: Looks like you are using the answer above as the basis of your next question, but didn't mark it as the valid answer or even provide an upvote.  That's pretty bad form :(